# Is it proper to publish a mobile app using test database and api in internal testing?

Tags: flutter, testing, android-testing, google-play-internal-testing

I have built a flutter app and i want that our testers will test the app through internal testing in google play using the test database and test api url.

This is doable but it has a drawback. In google play, you can actually use the same build that was published in **internal testing** to be published as a **release version**. Since I am using a test database and api on the build, i have to change the settings to use live version and build the apk and upload it again to google play to do so. So whenever i want to have a new release, i need to submit atleast **2 builds**.

Do you think this process is proper? If not, do you have any recommendation on how i can share the app to my testers that uses test environment. I have done things like sharing apk manually on microsoft teams but it doesn't feel like the right thing to do according to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the best approach would be to create a new [flavor](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors) for your `dev` environment instead of just building with differentet variables. Then you can create a new app at appstore named "yourapp dev" with different bundle id, e.g `com.yourapp.app.dev` and upload your dev builds to internal track of the new dev app. If you don't want to create a new dev app to playstore for distributing, you can also use firebase distribution to share your apk/ipa.

Comment: i think firebase app distribution will do, thanks!